# Binary Image Classification using convolutional layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a sample of images of chairs and tables and I want to use a neural network using convolutional layer and gpu-acceleration for training. This is what I have so far - how do I train the network?

```
chairs = Import["C:\\Users\\Murphy\\Samples\\chairs\\*"];
tables = Import["C:\\Users\\Murphy\\Samples\\tables\\*"];

$train = 300;
trainingData = <|"Chairs" -> chairs[[;; $train]], "Tables" -> tables[[;;$train]]|>;
testingData = <|"Chairs" -> chairs[[$train + 1 ;;]], "Tables" -> tables[[$train + 1 ;;]]|>;

module = NetChain[{ ConvolutionLayer[100, {3, 3}], BatchNormalizationLayer[], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1] }]

net = NetChain[{ module, module, module, module, FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}], "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", classes}]]

{time, trained} = AbsoluteTiming @ NetTrain[net, trainingData, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked documentation for `Classify`? That would be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: I tried the following:

Comment: module = NetChain[{ ConvolutionLayer[100, {3, 3}], BatchNormalizationLayer[], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1] }]

net = NetChain[{ module, module, module, module, FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}], "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", classes}]]

{time, trained} = AbsoluteTiming @ NetTrain[net, trainingData, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];

Comment: from this site: https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/accelerate-training-using-a-gpu.html?product=mathematica

Comment: Training a net for an image classification task from scratch is probably not a good idea when there are pre-trained models that you can use as feature extractors. Have a look at `NetModel` and google *transfer learning*